# Eliminate whitespace around single letters

Tags: regex, perl

I frequently receive PDFs that contain (when converted with `pdftotext`) whitespaces between the letters of some arbitrary words:

`This i s a n example t e x t that c o n t a i n s strange spaces.`

For further automated processing (looking for specific words) I would like to remove all whitespace between "standalone" letters (single-letter words), so the result would look like this:

`This isan example text that contains strange spaces.`

I tried to achieve this with a simple perl regex:

`s/ (\w) (\w) / $1$2 /g`

Which of course does not work, as after the first and second standalone letters have been moved together, the second one no longer is a standalone, so the space to the third will not match:

`This is a n example te x t that co n ta i ns strange spaces.`

So I tried lockahead assertions, but failed to achieve anything (also because I did not find any example that uses them in a substitution).

As usual with PRE, my feeling is, that there must be a very simple and elegant solution for this...

Comment: A simple program will require human correction. For example, `i s a n` will be turned into `isan`, and it requires knowledge of the language to know it is supposed to be two words.

Comment: My two cents: [match `\b(\w) +(?=\w\b)` and replace by `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/v5zHGw/1) (similar @TLP's answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just match a continuous series of single letters separated by spaces, then delete all spaces from that using a nested substitution (the /e eval modifier).

```
s{\b ((\w\s)+\w) \b}{ my $s = $1; $s =~ s/ //g; $s }xge;
```

Comment: Aaarg... nested substitution – I should have come to that myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It works fine.Not sure why you think otherwise. Note that I used /x and so those spaces in the pattern aren't part of the pattern.

Comment: @DaveMitchell I was wrong, that's why I deleted the comment. Curious optimization: `$1 =~ s/ //gr`.

Answer (score 3):

Excess whitespace can be removed with a regex, but Perl by itself cannot know what is correct English. With that caveat, this seems to work:

```
$ perl -pe's/(?<!\S)(\S) (?=\S )/$1/g' spaces.txt
This isan example text that contains strange spaces.
```

Note that `i s a n` cannot be distinguished from a normal 4 letter word, that requires human correction, or some language module.

Explanation:

- `(?<!\S)` negative look-behind assertion checks that the character behind is not a non-whitespace.
- `(\S)`  next must follow a non-whitespace, which we capture with parens, followed by a whitespace, which we will remove (or not put back, as it were).
- `(?=\S )` next we check with a look-ahead assertion that what follows is a non-whitespace followed by a whitespace. We do not change the string there.
- Then put back the character we captured with `$1`

It might be more correct to use `[^ ]` instead of `\S`. Since you only seem to have a problem with spaces being inserted, there is no need to match tabs, newlines or other whitespace. Feel free to do that change if you feel it is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! Now I also understand, why I didn't get the lockahead working - the first has to be a lock-behind. The `isan` is expected (as also shown in the question)'

Comment: @Daniel You're welcome. They can be tricky. The key is to remember they are zero-width, pointing in a direction.